# Drawing Diagonal Lines Across a Picture

Tags: python, coordinates, draw, jython, jes

I am trying to draw parallel lines diagonally from the top right corner to the bottom left corner of a picture. I want it to look like this (lovely paint pic)

[image: diag paint pic]

```
def diagTopLBottomR():
  pic=makePicture(pickAFile())
  w=getWidth(pic)
  h=getHeight(pic)
  x1=0
  y1=0
  x2=0
  y2=0
  i=0
  while i<11:
    x1=10*i
    y2=10*i
    i+=1
    for y in range (y1,y2):
      x = (y-y1)*(x2-x1)/(y2-y1) +x1
      px=getPixel(pic,x,y)
      color=makeColor(0,0,0)
      setColor(px, color)
  x3=0
  y3=h
  x4=w
  y4=0
  j=0
  while j<10:
    x3=10*j
    y4=10*j
    j+=1
    for y in range (y3,y4):
      x = (y-y3)*(x4-x3)/(y4-y3) +x3
      px=getPixel(pic,x,y)
      color=makeColor(0,0,0)
      setColor(px, color)

  return(pic)
```

**You'll note** that the x3 will either be max value, causing an outof range exception, or the y range will start with a higher value ie (y3>y4) and doesn't work in reverse, or when I decrement it. It's like a paradox.

The first loop is working, no matter what I try I cannot get the second loop to work. This is what I'm ending up with.

[image: diag lines]

Any ideas? Thanks.

---

**Edit**

I have played around with the ranges, and either get no result for the second loop, as shown above of an out of range exception.

I have tried:

```
  x3=0
  y3=h
  x4=w
  y4=0
  j=0
  while j<10:
    x3=10*j
    y4=10*j
    j+=1
    for x in range (x3,x4):
      y = (x-x3)*(y4-y3)/(x4-x3) +y3
```

---

*Stole Unicorns [from here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37328/my-godits-full-of-unicorns).*

Comment: Do you get an error? or does it just not show up

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the first part, `y1` is set to 0 and `y2` increases from 0 in the loop, so `y1 < y2`. This is fine because you use

```
for y in range (y1,y2)
```

In the second part, `y3` is set to `h` (128 in your case, I guess) and `y4` increases from 0 in the loop, so `y3 > y4`. This is NOT fine because you use

```
for y in range (y3,y4)
```

You could try stepping backwards by giving `range()` a third parameter indicating a step size of -1. Or you could switch `y3` and `y4` (be cautious of what this does to the rest of your code).

Comment: With all the x's and y's, there's a possibility of errors throughout. For example in the line `x = (y-y3)*(x4-x3)/(y4-y3) +x3`, `y4-y3` will be negative. Try to go through and find things like that.

Answer (score 5):

`range()` assumes the first parameter is less than the second parameter, and it goes in an ascending order.  You have:

```
for y in range (y3,y4):
```

where `y3=h` and `y4=0` (on the first pass).  Since y3 > y4, this loop does nothing.
You can use either:

```
for y in range(y4,y3):
```

or

```
for y in range(y3,y4,-1):
```

Answer (score 5):

In the second loop, `y3` is greater (or equal) than `y4`.  So, try `range (y4,y3)`.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by making `px=getPixel(pic,x,y-1)`  and using the suggested answers of decrementing y range.

```
def diagTopLBottomR():
  pic=makePicture(pickAFile())
  w=getWidth(pic)
  h=getHeight(pic)
  x1=0
  y1=0
  x2=0
  y2=0
  i=0
  while i<10:
    x1=10*i
    y2=10*i
    i+=1
    for y in range (y1,y2):
      x = (y-y1)*(x2-x1)/(y2-y1) +x1
      px=getPixel(pic,x,y)
      color=makeColor(0,0,0)
      setColor(px, color)
  x3=0
  y3=h
  x4=w
  y4=0
  j=0
  while j<10:
    x3=10*j
    y4=10*j
    j+=1
    for y in range (y3,y4,-1):#change here
      x = abs((y-y3)*(x4-x3)/(y4-y3) +x3)
      px=getPixel(pic,x,y-1)#change here
      color=makeColor(0,0,0)
      setColor(px, color)

  return(pic)
```

[image: pic]